# Which ubuntu derivative for my Netbook?

Tags: performance, ubuntu-netbook, compatibility, ideapad

I have an Lenovo Ideapad S10-2 Like this

Processor / Chipset
CPU Intel Atom N270 / 1.6 GHz 
Cache L2 cache - 512.0 KB 
Front Side Bus 533.0 MHz 
Chipset Mobile Intel 945GSE Express 
Features Hyper-Threading Technology

RAM 2.0 GB DDR2 SDRAM
533.0 MHz / PC2-5300 
Form Factor SO DIMM 200-pin

Audio & Video
Graphics Processor Intel GMA 950 
Memory Allocation Technology Dynamic Video Memory Technology 3.0

Which ubuntu derivative should i use for best driver and device performans compatibility

im a general purpose user frequently surf on internet, sometimes i need remote desktop connection, office extension document files, and video multimedia files.

Your suggestions are very important for me because windows slow down my system heaps of times..
so i want to use ubuntu anymore.

Thanks in advance, Best Regards

Comment: Here's running standard Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit on a netbook with similar specs (Samsung NC10 2GB) - not really a fast beast but still quite usable. You may try with GNOME classic session, or Unity-2D (both are still available in 12.04) for a faster desktop experience.

Comment: It might not be an official derivative, but [some users](http://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/1o2ua3/eos_breathed_life_into_my_netbook_new_convert_here/) have reported pretty good performance with elementary OS on their older netbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a machine with almost the same specs and Lubuntu is running very smooth on it. My recommendation is to go with Lubuntu.

Comment: as a side note: after installing Lubuntu, download and install ubuntu-restricted-extras in order to gain more features.

Comment: as another side note: after installing Lubuntu, download and install LXLauncher, a lightweight easy-mode launcher optimized for use with the 10" netbook form factor.

Answer (score 0):

All will contain similar programs, so that's not a problem. Course, you could just install more if you needed to. Here's what I'd say:
Lubuntu: Very fast but not quite as pretty as Xubuntu, similar Ui to win xp/vista.
Xubuntu: Still pretty fast but not as fast as Lubuntu, different Ui to win.
Kubuntu: Prettier than the others, much slower, similar Ui to win xp/vista or 7 if you change the panel settings.
I'd recommend L- or X- ubuntu for a netbook.

Answer (score 0):

Either Xubuntu or Lubuntu for low end specs, although you may be just fine with Unity if you turn off some of the pretty stuff.